# How can I input a conditional statement in ternary operator to return true or false in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the values ​​lightsstasut1error, lightsstasut2error, lightsstasut3error and the strips contain either "Y" or "N". At this time, I want to return true if at least one of the values ​​is N, and false if all of them are Y. So I wrote the code, and if there is even one N, it keeps returning false. How do I fix my code?

this is my code

```
  const errors2 = (lightstasut1error || lightstasut2error || lightstasut3error) === "N" ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 4):

CHange this to this

```
const errors2 = (lightstasut1error === "N" || lightstasut2error === "N" || lightstasut3error === "N")
```

Please check now

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: Is there any point in using the ternary operator here? `condition` and `condition ? true : false` is exactly the same.

Comment: yes correct, youre right @MarkoBorković thanks for the optimization

Comment: if it would have been returning something else, then it would have mattered